# Battery Positive Post Meltdown

Tags: electrical, battery, golf

On a series of 6 inline 8 volt batteries, what causes the meltdown of the positive post on one of the batteries?  Within the last two years we have had to replace 4 batteries in our golf cart.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Melting = Heat. Heat in an electrical circuit is caused by resistance. In your case, excessive resistance. If you're replacing batteries, one could guess that you are cleaning the posts and the inside of the connector to the post. That leaves the section where the connector attaches to the cable.

If it's a swedged-on cable end, you'll have to replace the entire cable, or cut off the suspect end and swedge on a new one. If it's a clamped-on type, it's still a good idea to cut off the end and add a new connector.

Examine the cable end for corrosion that may have traveled into the depths/length of the cable. A new cable will remove these concerns.

Reference material from [NDT Resource Center](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/HighSchool/Electricity/resistance.htm):

> If we are trying to transmit electricity from one place to another
>   through a conductor, resistance is undesirable in the conductor.
>   Resistance causes some of the electrical energy to turn into heat so
>   some electrical energy is lost along the way.

Comment: Heat is 'caused' by current, a result of a lack of resistance: conductance. If the conductance is too high, a short will occur and things burst into flames. If you short a battery far enough, it usually decreases the lifespan significantly.